# An error occurred - TFTP server did not start (triggered from HTTPProvisioning

Tags: java, tftp

im doing tr069 monitoring system, however get  this error. Im not expert in Java, so can someone suggest/advice what is the meaning of this error. there are too many error, i cannot find what is the root cause

```
2015-04-12 19:48:04.175 NOTICE HTTP/TFTP-Server and Telnet Provisioning Controller starts...
2015-04-12 19:48:04.192 NOTICE Starting TFTP Server on port 69.  Read directory: . Write directory: . Server Mode is GET_ONLY
2015-04-12 19:48:04.239 FATAL  An error occurred - TFTP server did not start (triggered from HTTPProvisioning
class java.net.SocketException:No such file or directory
java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:96)
java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:396)
java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:251)
java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:304)
java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:276)
org.apache.commons.net.DefaultDatagramSocketFactory.createDatagramSocket(DefaultDatagramSocketFactory.java:59)
org.apache.commons.net.DatagramSocketClient.open(DatagramSocketClient.java:119)
com.owera.xaps.spp.TFTPServer.launch(TFTPServer.java:252)
com.owera.xaps.spp.TFTPServer.<init>(TFTPServer.java:186)
com.owera.xaps.spp.HTTPProvisioning.<clinit>(HTTPProvisioning.java:49)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:140)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

below is the link for java documentation for this tftp server

1. https://github.com/freeacs/spp/blob/master/src/com/owera/xaps/spp/TFTPServer.java
2. https://github.com/freeacs/spp/blob/master/src/com/owera/xaps/spp/HTTPProvisioning.java

I already ask from freeacs forum but no one answer, So can someone help me to at least get a clue on what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the first line answers it:

```
class java.net.SocketException:No such file or directory
```

Maybe they have updated it since the time it happened.

Hope you had good luck!